# PHP Codeigniter - Handle multiple databases on the same server

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

If I write

```
$db1 = $this->load->database('data1',TRUE);
$db2 = $this->load->database('data2',TRUE);
```

and both databases are on the same server, does Codeigniter switch it without re-connect to the server? If not, there is a way to make it do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, The codeigniter core will take care of multiconnectivities. It gets and remembers the connection IDs and call them on database interactions. Just allow the "auto connect" feature to load and instantiate the database class with every page load. To enable "auto connecting", add the word database to the library array, as indicated in the following file:

```
application/config/autoload.php
```

for more info about database connection in codeigniter visit [ellislab.com](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)